# How to evaluate integral: $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{n} e^{-\alpha x^{2}} dx $ only using methods of multidimensional integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral, gaussian-integral

I need to solve this integral 
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{n} e^{-\alpha x^{2}} dx. $$
where n is natural number and $\alpha > 0$.

I know how to solve it using derivation according parameter $\alpha$ or with integration by parts but **my task is to solve it
using only methods of multidimensional integration**.I am not sure how to do so.I have tried to use
polar coordinates but without success.

It would be great if anyone can show me how to do so.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $n$ in the integrand?

Comment: Sorry, n is natural number

Comment: For odd $n$ the integral is obviously $0$.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that $n=2k$ since for odd $n$ the integral is obviously zero.

Hint:
Let
$$
I(\alpha,k)=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{2k}e^{-\alpha x^2}dx=\int_0^\infty x^{2k}e^{-\alpha x^2}dx.
$$

Then
$$
I^2(\alpha,k)=\int_0^\infty x^{2k}e^{-\alpha x^2}dx\int_0^\infty y^{2k}e^{-\alpha y^2}dy\\
=\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{2k}\theta\sin^{2k}\theta\,d\theta\int_0^\infty r^{2k+1}e^{-\alpha r^2}dr.
$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: It is exactly where i got to.But second integral in last row seems to be same problem but it can be solved using gamma function i hope.

Comment: how is it so obvious  that  we can say that integrals in first row are same?I see it is symmetric and so on but interval is unrestricted.Is it not problem or how we can show it is right?

Comment: The second integral is elementary after you consider the differential to be $dr^2$. And the first integral can be expressed via the Beta function.

Comment: The integrals are the same because the integrand is an even function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with partial integration with $u=x^{n-1}$ and $dv=xe^{-\alpha x^2}dx$, then use induction.

Comment: Yeah, sorry i need to change my post. I need to use only method of multidimensional integration.

Comment: You will probably need some induction again. You can use method of multidimensional integration to solve $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\alpha x^2}$. To do that you can integrate $e^{-\alpha(x^2+y^2)}$ over $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$I(n)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^ne^{-ax^2}dx$$
$$I'(n)=n\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{n-1}e^{-ax^2}dx=nI(n-1)$$
$$I''(n)=n(n-1)I(n-2)$$
and we know that:
$$I(n)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{I^{(i)}(a)}{i!}(n-a)^i$$
choosing $a=0$ we get:
$$I(n)=\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{n!}{(n-i)!i!}n^iI(n-i)$$

---

Using the total derviative definition we can also show that:
$$I(N,A)=N\int_0^N\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{n-1}e^{-ax^2}dxda-2\int_0^A\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{n+1}e^{-ax^2}dxda$$